# Unable to create an object of type 'MyEFCoreDbContext' xaf Blazor EFCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, blazor-server-side, xaf

I created a new project with the XAF Blazor 20.2.3 wizard
and upgraded the EFCore packages to 5.0.
In PM I ran

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

However when I run

```
add-migration initial
```

I get

> Unable to create an object of type 'ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I have looked at the link but I don't think it applies to the xaf Blazor app.

I tried commenting out the Database Initializer

```cs
using System;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.Updating;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF.PermissionPolicy;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.DesignTime;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base;
namespace ExamBuddy.Module.BusinessObjects {
    public class ExamBuddyContextInitializer : DbContextTypesInfoInitializerBase {
        protected override DbContext CreateDbContext() {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(@";");
            return new ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
    //[TypesInfoInitializer(typeof(ExamBuddyContextInitializer))]
    public class ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext : DbContext {
        public ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext> options) : base(options) {
        }
        public DbSet<ModuleInfo> ModulesInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModelDifference> ModelDifferences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModelDifferenceAspect> ModelDifferenceAspects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PermissionPolicyRole> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PermissionPolicyRoleBase> RolesBase { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PermissionPolicyUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CourseUnit> CourseUnits { get; set; }
         
    }
```

[Update]

I set the module project to be the start project then I ran

```
add-migration initial -verbose
```

the result was

> Startup project 'ExamBuddy.Module' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project, and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core. For more information on using the EF Core Tools with .NET Standard projects, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2034705

[Update]

Cross linking to [the Dev Express ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t952240/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-myefcoredbcontext)

I added the following to the ExamBuddy.Blazor.Server

```
    public class ExamBuddyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext>
    {
        public ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Pooling=false;Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=ExamBuddy;ConnectRetryCount=0;");
            return new ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Experimenting in Package Manager Console and Adding ConsoleApp1 I have

```
PM> add-migration init
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Startup project 'ExamBuddy.Module' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project, and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core. For more information on using the EF Core Tools with .NET Standard projects, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2034705
```

So I added ConsoleApp1 as a 3.1 .net core start up project and added references to the XAF projects

```
PM> add-migration init
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext'.
```

For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

The source is [on GitHub](https://github.com/kgreed/ExamBuddy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the ExamBuddyContextFactory class as advised in the DevExpress ticket
in the Module project and was then able to create the initial migration.

```
public class ExamBuddyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext>
{
    public ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Pooling=false;Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=ExamBuddy;ConnectRetryCount=0;");
        return new ExamBuddyEFCoreDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: However I get an error trying to run update-database. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076988/provider-sni-pn11-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-specified

Comment: And this is coming form DevEx support, seriously? When using verbatim strings, one should use single backslash, i.e. `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`, otherwise *Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid*.

Comment: appsettings.json has "ConnectionString": "Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false;Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=ExamBuddy" and that was working ok.